# Chaining a Function with a BiFunction in Java

Tags: java, functional-programming, functional-interface

I have a `Function` and `BiFunction` and I would like to chain them

```
Function<Integer, String> function = n -> "" + n;
BiFunction<String, Boolean, List<Character>> biFunction =
    (str, isOK) -> Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
```

Is there a way to chain these two Functions such as the returned value from `Function` is used as an input to `BiFunction`?

*Pseudocode:*

```
public List<Character> myMethod(int n, boolean isOK) {
    return function.andThen(biFunction).apply([output_of_function], isOK)
}
```

I couldn't find a way to provide the integer `n` to `Function` nor to supply `BiFunction` with the output of the first `Function`.

Is it doable?

Comment: You mean you want to do `function.andThen(biFunction).apply(n, isOK)`? If you compose these two functions, you end up with something that takes an `Integer` and a `Boolean`.

Comment: Not really. I would like to the integer with the first function. The result will be used as an input to the biFunction

Comment: Ah I see, so you just want a `Function<Boolean, List<Character>>` as the result, not a `BiFunction`. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default methods [`andThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen(java.util.function.Function)) and [`compose()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#compose(java.util.function.Function)) declared in the interface `Function` expect another `Function` as an argument. Hence, it's not possible to fuse `Function` and `BiFunction` using these methods (`BiFunction` *and* `Function` *doesn't extend each other*).

On the other hand method [`BiFunction.andThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/function/BiFunction.html#andThen(java.util.function.Function)) expects a `Function` as argument. But unfortunately it would be applied **after** `BiFunction` (i.e. on the result produced by the `BiFunction`), but you need the opposite, so this option doesn't fit into your use-case.

As a possible workaround, you can combine a `Function` and a `BiFunction` into an aggregate `BiFunction` expecting the input of the `Function` function and a `boolean` value and producing the result generated by the by `BiFunction` like this:

```
public static <T, R, RR> BiFunction<T, Boolean, RR> getCombinedFunction(
    Function<T, R> fun, BiFunction<R, Boolean, RR> biFun
) {
    
    return (t, isOk) -> biFun.apply(fun.apply(t), isOk);
}
```

It can be used in the following way:

```
Function<Integer, String> function = // initializing function
BiFunction<String, Boolean, List<Character>> biFunction =  // initializing biFunction
    
List<Character> chars = getCombinedFunction(function, biFunction).apply(12345, true);
```

**Sidenote:**

The preferred way of converting an `int` into a `String` is to use `static` method `String.valueOf()`. And the function from your example could be expressed as the following method reference:

```
Function<Integer, String> function = String::valueOf;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a generic method that compose Function and BiFunction like this.

```
public static <A, B, C, D> BiFunction<A, C, D> compose(Function<A, B> f, BiFunction<B, C, D> bf) {
    return (a, c) -> bf.apply(f.apply(a), c);
}
```

And you can use like this.

```
Function<Integer, String> function = n -> ""+n;
BiFunction<String, Boolean, List<Character>> biFunction = (str, isOK) -> Collections.emptyList();

public List<Character> myMethod(int n, boolean isOK) {
    return compose(function, biFunction).apply(n, isOK);
}
```

Node: You should use `Collections.emptyList()` instead of `Collections.EMPTY_LIST`.
The latter gives a warning.